# Reusing HttpConnection obtained from Server to be used in HttpClient

Tags: java, java-11, apache-httpcomponents, apache-httpclient-5.x

I have a task to create an module that will contain a server to which will be sent `HTTP` requests. For each such request the `HttpConnection` (or `Socket`) should be obtained and reused by http client to send back requests using same connection.

The opposite thing will be done on the other side - reusing connection from http client (which initiates communication) to http server, which will use that connection to listen for incoming requests.

As a server and server related libraries I am not fixed to any technology, can use whatever fits best.

Providing I am in GET method of SpringBoot Controller I need something like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/{switchConnection}")
void switchConnection(@RequestBody HttpServletRequest request) {
    FansyServerConnection srvConn = request.getConnection();
    HttpURLConnection clientConn = convertToClinetConn(srvConn);
    clientConn.setRequestMethod("GET");

    // start sending requests with clientConn 
}
```

I have seen such implementation in Go which literally is some lines of code. There is `Hijack()` method to get connection from server and reuse it in http client.

This module will run inside SpringBoot, as a part of an web application, that neededs to communicate with third party application.

I have two choices: using some standard libraries like Apache `httpcomponents` or Java 11 `HttpClient`  or other related ones or as an alternative implementing my own Server using `Socket`s.

By now could not find proper libraries for this and am afraid will need to go to lower level using sockets.
Any help with the libraries is appreciated.

Comment: Java's `HttpURLConnection` does that automatically for you on the client side, and any competently written HTTP server should keep the incoming connection alive on the server side subject to a timeout.

Comment: The problem actually is that I need to create the `HttpUrlConnection` with the socket gotten from server. And this seems to be impossible.
The use case is: we have server that after first request to it turns into http client. And the connection that we have in the server (from this first request) needs to be used in the client.

In other words: we receive http request and using the connection of that request, we start sending many requests to the initiator of that request, which meanwhile was turned from http client to http server.

Comment: @jascadev have you got any solution for this problem, please share if you got any